# Why did I get [object HTMLParagraphElement]

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie. Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function replyOne () {
        document.getElementById("comment_content").value = document.getElementById("username")
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="username">Jack</p>
    <textarea id="comment_content" ></textarea>
    <button onclick="replyOne()">Copy Text</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expect that when I click the button, it will copy 'Jack' to the textarea. 
But instead it just writes '[object HTMLParagraphElement]'.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It should be:

```
document.getElementById("comment_content").value =
    document.getElementById("username").innerHTML
```

Without the `.innerHTML`, it will try to copy in the actual element, not its content.

Comment: @hsming: don't forget to tick (accept) answers that worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use textContent,innertext,innerHTML.But two of them are browser specific and innerHTML can work on three major browser.

Also you can parse the dom by parent children combination and will get required value.

```
 function replyOne () {
    document.getElementById("comment_content").value=document.getElementById("username").innerHTML;

    //OR 
    document.getElementById("comment_content").value=document.getElementById("username").textContent;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract what you are looking for using the `obj.innerText` attribute and you will solve the problem-:

```js
var t= document.getElementById("comment_content");
var text=t.innerText;
alert(t);
```

Comment: You were only 61 when that answer was already given tho :). And also the reason why it should be avoided (does not work on all browsers).

Answer (score -1):

**This is solution of [objectHTMLParagraphElement] with example**

```
var sel = document.getElementById('ex').innerHTML; // without innerHTML this will 
comes [objectHTMLParagraphElement]
var txt = sel + "Hello";    
document.write(txt); // output Hello
```