# Why do i have [object HTMLParagraphElement]?

Tags: javascript

I'm little confused about this :

```
var SessionStorage = {
    station_name: 'TEST',
    set_name_station: sessionStorage.setItem('name_station', this.station_name),
    get_name_station: sessionStorage.getItem('name_station'),

    launch_functions_sessionStorage: function () {
        this.onReservation();
    },

    onReservation: function () {
        console.log(this.get_name_station)
    }
};
```

I'm trying to save 'TEST' in my sessionStorage Key.

I have this return "[object HTMLParagraphElement]"

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: `this.station_name` in `sessionStorage.setItem` does not refer to `SessionStorage.station_name`, since `set_name_station` is not a function. It appears you're storing an HTMLParagraphElement in your session storage.

Comment: Kindly check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147488/why-did-i-get-object-htmlparagraphelement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to create a `get/set` methods for `name_station` setting. But instead of methods creation you just assign the results of invocation of `sessionStorage.setItem / sessionStorage.getItem`.

What you can probably do is:

`var SessionStorage = {
    ...
    set_name_station: function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem('name_station', this.station_name)
    },
    get_name_station: function() {
        sessionStorage.getItem('name_station'),
    }
    ...
};`

In this sample `set_name_station/get_name_station` are functions, so you can use them like: 

    `...
    SessionStorage.set_name_station();
    SessionStorage.get_name_station();`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 var SessionStorage = {
   station_name: 'TEST',
   set_name_station: function () {
     sessionStorage.setItem('name_station', this.station_name)
   }
 };
```

Comment: I'm gonna do that